# Is there an Equivalent to before_filter from rails in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot

Started programming in SpringBoot coming from Rails and can't fine the equivalent to before_filter. I just want to add simple functions that happen before my controllers get called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`HandlerInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) which have the following methods allow you to execute some codes when some events happens:

- `preHandle(..)`: Before the actual controller method is executed
- `postHandle(..)`: After the controller method is executed
- `afterCompletion(..)`: After the complete request has finished

Once you create a `HandlerInterceptor` , you can register by adding it to the `InterceptorRegistry` :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyHandlerInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Comment: from the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration `If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features and you want to add additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view controllers, and other features), you can add your own @Configuration class of type WebMvcConfigurer but without @EnableWebMvc`

Comment: Thanks the additional information. @Totic , please aware of this behaviour. `@EnableWebMvc` means you want to take complete control of spring mvc and ignore those spring boot mvc feature. But whatever configure you use , you have to add the the interceptor to `InterceptorRegistry`